# How to create a theme in material ui v5 and import it, including classes?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have been struggling with this problem all day, and i seriously have no idea how to fix it. Its about material ui5.

I have been following a tutorial that uses v4 and its syntax is different, so i have been trying to change it to material ui version 5 but it has been an impossible job.

Below you can find the code that i currently have, as you can see it has the theme object inside the header component, which i don't want. I want to be able to import it and use it. As you can also see theme const changes the default options from the theme object in uiv5. Also, the return in the components header uses classes. Which point to the theme const. So how can i import it, and use the styles exactly as they are laid out? I only want to be able to use those styles in the header component no matter how.

````
> import React from 'react';
> import {Autocomplete} from '@react-google-maps/api';
> import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, InputBase, Box} from '@mui/material'
> import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search'
> import { ThemeProvider, useTheme, createTheme, alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
> 
> const Header = () => {
> 
>     const classes = useTheme();
> 
>     const theme = createTheme({
>         title: {
>           display: 'none',
>           [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
>             display: 'block',
>           },
>         },
>         search: {
>           position: 'relative',
>           borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
>           backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
>           '&:hover': { backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25) },
>           marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
>           marginLeft: 0,
>           width: '100%',
>           [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: { marginLeft: theme.spacing(3), width: 'auto' },
>         },
>         searchIcon: {
>           padding: theme.spacing(0, 2), height: '100%', position: 'absolute', pointerEvents: 'none', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',
>         },
>         inputRoot: {
>           color: 'inherit',
>         },
>         inputInput: {
>           padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0), paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`, transition: theme.transitions.create('width'), width: '100%', [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: { width: '20ch' },
>         },
>         toolbar: {
>           display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between',
>         },
>       })
> 
> 
> 
>     return (
>         
>         <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
>         <AppBar position='static'>
>             <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
>                 <Typography variant = 'h5' className={classes.title}>
>                      Travel Advisor
>                 </Typography>
>                 <Box display = 'flex'>
>                 <Typography variant = 'h6' className={classes.title}>
>                      Explore new places
>                 </Typography>
>                 {/*<Autocomplete>*/}
>                     <div className={classes.search}>
>                        <div className={classes.searchIcon}> 
>                        <SearchIcon />
>                        </div>
>                     </div>
>                 {/*<Autocomplete>*/}
>                 </Box>
>             </Toolbar>
>         </AppBar>
>         </ThemeProvider >
>     )
> 
> }
> 
>  
> 
> export default Header
> ```
````

```
>                        <InputBase placeholder="Search..." classes={{root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput}}/>
```